# How to change numerical data to custom text words in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

The below query is grabbing data and creating a CSV file, the issue that I am having is that the source called ‘SPLE’ stores data in the database with numbers of 0, 1, 50.

However in the CSV those numbers are being collected in the CSV and I would like somehow when creating the CSV those number to represent words such as,

0 = True

1 = False

50 = Pending

Could someone show me how this is done please, I have been struggling on this?

My Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST*"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'SPLE': 'TAG', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names) 
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

The output in the CSV file is:

```
Date    SPLE    Venue
20171016    1   Central
20171016    0   Central
20171016    50  Central
```

Comment: Can you please post an example result of how query result `res` looks?

Comment: Date TAG     Class  Venue 
20171016 0 5 Central
20171016 1 5 Central
20171016 1 5 Central
20171016 0 5 Central
20171016 50 5 Central
20171016 0 5 Central
20171016 0 5 Central
20171016 1 5 Central

Comment: i am not sure if you can understand the output in the comment section? but the TAG column has number and i would like Text which represent the numbers. if that make sense

Comment: I'm unable to understand the query output. Can you please add the formatted result in the question.

Comment: @Harman, i have added the output and showing you each column. The one  i am having issues with is the TAG column  where i want the numbers to represent text but in the database the values are stored with numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change numerical data to text in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784832/change-numerical-data-to-text-in-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `mycsvfile.csv` file have SPLE column.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST*"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)


import pandas as pd 


SPLE = {0:'true',1:'false',50:'pending'}

saved_csv = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile.csv',sep='\t')

saved_csv['SPLE'] = saved_csv['SPLE'].map(lambda x: SPLE[int(x)])

saved_csv.to_csv('edited_csv.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: also i am getting a error of -     import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: @Rich I'm updating my code. You need to install python pandas using `pip install pandas`

Comment: i tried installing pandas and getting connection timeout. is there another way to do this?

Comment: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x037D55D0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/

Comment: @Rich try downloading wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas). The navigate to the downloaded folder and do `pip install wheel_file_name.whl`

Comment: thanks Harman, however i have updated my code so the file name prints out the current date and time. will your code still work with my update?

Comment: stil not working the pip install - 

$ pip install pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64

Collecting pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x01F9F030>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas-0-20-3-cp27-cp27m-win-amd64/

Comment: is there another way to do this? thanks for taking a look

Comment: @Rich You forgot to add .whl at the end of the downloaded file. Try `pip install pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` Let me know if this wasn't the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156842/discussion-between-harman-and-rich).

Comment: I think using `pandas` for such a simple task is pretty much overkill.

Comment: @Harman - got another error of - pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a dict somewhere for doing the translation:

```
SPLE_TRANSLATION = {0: 'True', 1: 'False', 50: 'Pending'}
```

Then, inside your loop:

```
my_dict['SPLE'] = SPLE_TRANSLATION[my_dict['SPLE']]
w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: i added your code to mine and it didnt work, maybe im not placing it correctly in my code