# Change numerical data to text in CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch

The below query is grabbing data and creating a CSV file, the issue that I am having is that the source called ‘SPLE’ stores data in the database with numbers of 0, 1, 50.

However in the CSV those numbers are being collected in the CSV and I would like somehow when creating the CSV those number to represent words such as,

0 = True

1 = False

50 = Pending

Could someone show me how this is done please, I have been struggling on this?

My Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST*"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'SPLE': 'TAG', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names) 
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

The output in the CSV file is:

```
Date       SPLE     Venue
20171016    1       Central
20171016    1       Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    50      Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    1       Central
```

FYI:

I have tried to use pandas however I am unable to install pandas so I am wondering if there is another way around this?

Comment: Change the contents of `my_dict` as per your needs before `w.writerow(my_dict)` in the for loop.

Comment: could you show me please? i think i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value before you write it to the csv:

```
mapping = {0:  "True",
           1:  "False",
           50: "Pending"}
# Map `SPLE`
sple = my_dict['SPLE']
my_dict['SPLE'] = mapping.get(int(sple), sple)

# Map `NME`
nme = my_dict['NME']
my_dict['NME'] = mapping.get(int(nme), nme)


w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working. i am adding your code before my  w.writerow(my_dict)

Comment: I made a slight modification (convert sple to int).

Comment: thank you this is working!!!! i wanted to ask if i wanted to do this to other columns how would i do that. i have 4 to 5 more columns that i want to change numbers to text? is there a way ?

Comment: Of course you can just adopt the behaviour and apply it to other columns.

Comment: could you show me, i thought i could do this by - sple = my_dict['SPLE','NME']
        my_dict['SPLE','NME'] = mapping.get(int(sple), sple) But not luck, it gave me a error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rich/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/TRY.py", line 76, in <module>
    sple = my_dict['SPLE','NME]
KeyError: ('SPLE','NME)

Comment: You have to do this one by one. (added nme)

Comment: thanks that works thank you. could i ask one more thing please. lets say there are 3 columns that have the number 0 but within each of those 3 column the number 0 means different such as, columns one 0 = yes column two 0 = red and column three 0 = fast. with the code you given me which works but it gives 0 a default of true. how would i be able to assign 0 to other words in different columns?

Comment: Just create another mapping dictionary and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the contents of my_dict, this is just a best guess but I'll try and assist stating my assumptions.

For a `my_dict` that is like the following:

```
my_dict = {"DATE": ..., "SPLE": ..., ...}
```

Before `w.writerow(my_dict)` you could parse the `SPLE` entry into what you want with:

```
my_dict["SPLE"] = str(bool(int(my_dict["SPLE"]))) if int(my_dict["SPLE"]) in [0,1] else "Pending"
```

The is a compact form of:

```
# Check to see if current "SPLE" value can be described 
# as True (1) or False (0)
if int(my_dict["SPLE"]) in [0,1]:
    # Yes it can, so change it to True or False string by type conversion
    my_dict["SPLE"] = str(bool(int(my_dict["SPLE"])))
else:
    # Entry is not a 0 or 1 so not described by true or false
    # assign to "Pending"
    my_dict["SPLE"] = "Pending"
```

Comment: could you show me where i would add this in my code. i added it before my w.writerow but it failed.

Comment: Write before `w.writerow()` should do it. Can you post your error, and print a line `my_dict` for me (put `print(my_dict)` straight after `my_dict = doc['_source']`)?

Comment: I made some edits that may fix your it from not working. If not, if you could provide what I requested in the last comment I can help more.